# Font Awesome Icon Appearing Under Text Box

Tags: html, css

I have a header on my page and there is a box containing a login picture and your website balance. But i'm trying to add a drop down menu with options but or some reason my Font Awesome icon is appearing under the text box. Basically I just want to understand why my Font Awesome icon is appearing under my text box. Any help?

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nxt4Lzch/

```
<head>
    <!--Script Links-->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="js/loading.js"></script>

    <!--Stylesheet Links-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" text="text/css" href="css/dropdown.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" text="text/css" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">

    <!--Font Links-->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <!--Website Header-->
    <div id="header">
        <div class="steam-box">
            <div class="steam-info">
                <img class="steam-avatar" src="<?=$steamprofile['avatar'];?>">
                <div class="balance-box">
                    <i class="fa fa-database">
                        <span class="balance-amount">$201.50</span>
                    </i>
                </div>
                <div class="steam-dropdown">
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!--Website Sidebar-->
    <div id="sidebar-menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#"><i class=""></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-area-chart"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-life-ring"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-cart-arrow-down"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-shopping-basket"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-users"></i></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

```
/* Default Stuff */
* {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    text-decoration:none;
    list-style:none;
    font-family:"Open Sans", sans-serif;
}

/* Website Header */
#header {
    background:rgb(28,28,28);
    width:100%;
    height:60px;
    position:absolute;
    box-shadow:0px 0px 8px 2px black;
    border-top:3px solid rgb(235,50,50);
    z-index:99999999;
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
}

/* Header (Steam Section) */
.steam-box {
    background:rgb(50,50,50);
    border-left:3px solid rgb(235,50,50);
    width:180px;
    height:40px;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:999999999;
    top:10px;
    left:1160px;
}

.steam-avatar {
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    margin-left:5px;
    margin-top:3px;
    border:2px solid rgb(28,28,28);
    border-radius:10px;
}

.balance-box {
    height:30px;
    width:100px;
    border-radius:10px;
    position:absolute;
    margin-top:5px;
    margin-left:5px;
    display:inline;
    background:rgb(28,28,28);
}

.balance-box i {
    color:rgb(255,255,255);
    line-height:30px;
    margin-left:10px;
}

.balance-amount {
    color:rgb(255,255,255);
    font-family:"Montserrat", sans-serif;
    margin-right:10px;
}

.steam-dropdown i {
    color:rgb(255,255,255);
    font-size:8px;
}

/* Sidebar Menu */
#sidebar-menu {
    background:rgb(41,41,41);
    width:60px;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:60px;
    box-shadow:4px 4px 8px black;
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
}

#sidebar-menu ul {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    margin-top:3px;
}

#sidebar-menu ul li {
    list-style:none;
    height:60px;
    border-bottom:2px solid rgb(17,17,17);
}

#sidebar-menu ul li a {
    color:rgb(255,255,255);
    font-size:30px;
    display:block;
    height:100%
    width:100%;
}

#sidebar-menu ul li a:hover {
    background:rgb(255,255,255);
    color:rgb(41,41,41);
}

#sidebar-menu ul li a:active {
    font-size:25px;
}
```

Comment: please check your fiddle again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because your `steam-dropdown` that contains the `font-awesome icon` is not `display:inline;`, Instead it is `display:block;` by default. Therefore it needs a new line.

Now if you add `display:inline;` to this `steam-dropdown` then it will move in the same line, but it goes under `.balance-box` because you are setting `position:absolute;` to this `.balance-box`. You have to remove that.

I suggest removing `position:absolute;` from `.balance-box` and Use flex on their parent div (which is `.steam-info`). By adding this in the your css:

```
.steam-info{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  align-items:center;
}
.steam-dropdown i {
  margin-left:5px;
}
```

This solves the problem asked. But might I suggest replacing `left:1160px;` with `right:20px;` in the css for `.steam-info` because in smaller screens it goes way too right. I have included this in my solution but you may remove this if you don't want that.

Here is a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nxt4Lzch/2/).

And here is a working Snippet:

```css
/* Default Stuff */
* {
 margin:0px;
 padding:0px;
 text-decoration:none;
 list-style:none;
 font-family:"Open Sans", sans-serif;
}

/* Loading Animation */
#loading-overlay {
 height:100%;
 width:100%;
 background:rgb(17,17,17);
 position:fixed;
 z-index:9999999999;
 left:0px;
 top:0px;
}

.loading-spinner {
 width:100px;
 height:100px;
 border:2px solid rgb(255,255,255);
 border-top:3px solid rgb(250,32,32);
 border-radius:100%;
 position:absolute;
 top:0px;
 bottom:0px;
 left:0px;
 right:0px;
 margin:auto;
 animation:loading-spin 1s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes loading-spin {
 from {
  transform:rotate(0deg);
 } to {
  transform:rotate(360deg);
 }
}

/* Website Header */
#header {
 background:rgb(28,28,28);
 width:100%;
 height:60px;
 position:absolute;
 box-shadow:0px 0px 8px 2px black;
 border-top:3px solid rgb(235,50,50);
 z-index:99999999;
 left:0px;
 top:0px;
}

/* Header (Steam Section) */
.steam-box {
 background:rgb(50,50,50);
 border-left:3px solid rgb(235,50,50);;
 width:180px;
 height:40px;
 position:absolute;
 z-index:999999999;
 top:10px;
 right:20px;
}

.steam-avatar {
 width:30px;
 height:30px;
 margin-left:5px;
 margin-top:3px;
 border:2px solid rgb(28,28,28);
 border-radius:10px;
}

.balance-box {
 height:30px;
 width:100px;
 border-radius:10px;
 //position:absolute;
 margin-top:5px;
 margin-left:5px;
 display:inline;
 background:rgb(28,28,28);
}

.balance-box i {
 color:rgb(255,255,255);
 line-height:30px;
 margin-left:10px;
}

.balance-amount {
 color:rgb(255,255,255);
 font-family:"Montserrat", sans-serif;
 margin-right:10px;
}

.steam-dropdown i {
 color:rgb(255,255,255);
 font-size:8px;
}

/* Sidebar Menu */
#sidebar-menu {
 background:rgb(41,41,41);
 width:60px;
 height:100%;
 position:absolute;
 text-align:center;
 line-height:60px;
 box-shadow:4px 4px 8px black;
 left:0px;
 top:0px;
}

#sidebar-menu ul {
 margin:0px;
 padding:0px;
 margin-top:3px;
}

#sidebar-menu ul li {
 list-style:none;
 height:60px;
 border-bottom:2px solid rgb(17,17,17);
}

#sidebar-menu ul li a {
 color:rgb(255,255,255);
 font-size:30px;
 display:block;
 height:100%
 width:100%;
}

#sidebar-menu ul li a:hover {
 background:rgb(255,255,255);
 color:rgb(41,41,41);
}

#sidebar-menu ul li a:active {
 font-size:25px;
}

.steam-info{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  align-items:center;
}
.steam-dropdown{
  flex-grow:1;
}
.steam-dropdown a{
  display:block;
  width:100%;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  height:100%;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <!--Loading Animation
  <div id="loading-overlay">
   <div class="loading-spinner"></div>
  </div>-->

  <!--Website Header-->
  <div id="header">
   <div class="steam-box">
  <? if(isset($_SESSION['steamid'])) {?>
    <div class="steam-info">
     <img class="steam-avatar" src="http://www.chinabuddhismencyclopedia.com/en/images/thumb/b/b8/Nature.jpg/240px-Nature.jpg">
     <div class="balance-box">
      <i class="fa fa-database">
       <span class="balance-amount">$201.50</span>
      </i>
     </div>
     <div class="steam-dropdown">
      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></a>
     </div>
    </div>
  <? } else {?>
   
  <? } ?>
   </div>
  </div>

  <!--Website Sidebar-->
  <div id="sidebar-menu">
   <ul>
    <li><a href="#"><i class=""></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-area-chart"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-life-ring"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-cart-arrow-down"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-shopping-basket"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-users"></i></a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: Ok just one more question. How do I perfectly find the center so I can align my icon between the box on the left and the end of the box on the right?

Comment: ok. I understand your question. but I dont have excess to my pc right now. can yiu please wait till I get hime.